# Conditions in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

This is a part of my layout:

```
.container
  .brand
   = render 'layouts/nav'
   .row
    - flash.each do |key, msg|
      = content_tag :p, msg, :class => "flash #{key}"
    = yield
```

The _nav partial is a large dropdown. When the visitor is for example on the /locale/umbria page I want to show umbria content in the dropdown and when the visitor is on the tuscany page I want to show tuscany content.

A part of large dropdown content is a translated object.

```
= t('navigation.nav.short_intro_umbria')
or
= t('navigation.nav.short_intro_tuscany')
```

How show i the short_intro_umbria content when the visitor is on the umbria page and the short_intro_tuscany content when the visitor is on the tuscany page?

How can I do this? Must I use conditions in the view layer?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not how translations work. The whole point is that the view doesn't change. You should have *one* view, which outputs something with no reference to location at all...

```
= t 'navigation.nav.short_intro'
```

And than you create multiple locale files in `config/locale/*.yml`. All you then do is swap out the locale file.

Comment: the translation was an example. I want the know how i can show content in the partial based on the url path. must i use conditions in the view layer?

Comment: Then yes, use an `if` statement.